# Golang lint for return statement after render

Tags: go

If you don't write a `return` after a render statement, you'll send multiple HTTP statuses back to the client. I'd really like to avoid this since it could both have security implications but also is just... weird behavior.

Example:

```
if passwordNotCorrect {
    w.WriteHeader(http.StatusUnauthorized)
    render.JSON(w, r, nil)
    return // If this is missing, we will return both 401 and 200.
}

w.WriteHeader(http.StatusOK)
render.JSON(w, r, nil)
return
```

Is there any linter out there that could warn you about this, to avoid silly mistakes?

Comment: afaik there's no linting option. proper tests covering use cases should help

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a decent case for unit tests. A mock would happily fail with something like you have described:

```
// foo.go

package foo

type Foo struct{
  render Renderer
}

func New(r Renderer) *Foo {
  return &Foo{render: r}
}

func (f *Foo) ServeHTTP(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
  if passwordNotCorrect {
    w.WriteHeader(http.StatusUnauthorized)
    render.JSON(w, r, nil)
    return // If this is missing, we will return both 401 and 200.
  }

  w.WriteHeader(http.StatusOK)
  render.JSON(w, r, nil)
  return
}
```

Now for the test...

```
// foo_test.go

package foo_test

import (
  "github.com/something/whatever/foo"
  "github.com/golang/mock/gomock"
)

//go:generate mockgen --source=foo.go --destination=mock_test.go --package=foo_test

func TestFoo(t *testing.T) {
  ctrl := gomock.NewController(t)
  defer ctrl.Finish()

  mockRenderer := NewMockRenderer(ctrl)
  mockRenderer.
    EXPECT().
    JSON(gomock.Any(), gomock.Any(), gomock.Any()) // This will fail JSON is invoked twice

  f := foo.New(mockRenderer)
  req := httptest.NewRequest(http.MethodGet, "http://some.url", nil)
  f.ServeHTTP(httptest.NewRecorder(), req)
}
```

This assumes that `render` is not a package. Then some adjustments will be necessary.